# How to stop internal publishing of nested structure groups when parent is published

Tags: 2013-sp1, custom-resolver

We are trying to restrict the publishing of nested SG's when parent SG is published.

We tried using Custom resolver and it seems to be working fine by removing the nested SG's.

Requirement is to sometimes allow the basic behavior of publishing Nested SG's based on some conditions using some GUI option.

We are trying to integrate it using a GUI extension along with coreservices but using coreservice ,we are not able to restrict the publishing of nested SG's.
Let us know if any way is there to allow both the ways based on conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would keep using your existing resolver and use ApplicationData (on the transaction) to store the options chosen in the UI. The resolver can then read the app data and decide whether or not to remove the child Structure Groups from the transaction.